# ISNUMBER() in an array formula doesn't recognise numbers as numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a workbook (attached) where a user enters the area of different crops on one worksheet (`Initial data collection sheet`) and then, in theory, a second worksheet generates a list of all crops that they have present (i.e. non-zero but numeric vales in the `Area` column). The formula I'm using is:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Initial data collection sheet'!A$40:A$103,SMALL(
   IF('Initial data collection sheet'!B$40:B$103<>"",
   IF('Initial data collection sheet'!B$40:B$103<>0,
   IF(ISNUMBER(B$40:B$103),
   ROW('Initial data collection sheet'!A$40:A$103)-ROW('Initial data collection sheet'!A$40)+1))),
   ROWS('Initial data collection sheet'!A$40:'Initial data collection sheet'!A40))),
   "NONE")}
```

where `Initial data collection sheet` column `A` is a list of possible crops and `Initial data collection sheet` column `B` is the column for areas.

The formula worked fine without the `ISNUMBER()` function included but because there are two text headings in the middle of the range, it meant that I was getting the headings listed as well as the crops present, which is not good. With `ISNUMBER()` included, it thinks there are no crops present irrespective of what numbers are in the area column.

Using the formula evaluation tool, I have worked out that this is because the `ISNUMBER()` function evaluates to a `FALSE` for all cells in my range, numbers or not. `NOT(ISTEXT())` does the same as having no `ISNUMBER()` clause - it also gives me the headings as it evaluates `NOT(ISTEXT())` as `FALSE` for every cell in the range irrespective of value.

I have tried manually changing the format of all the column `B` cells to numeric, as well as using the 'clear all' function on the cells and re-entering every value manually, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea why the `ISNUMBER()`/`NOT(ISTEXT())` doesn't work, and how I might otherwise remove the two headings from the list of crops present?

A reduced version of the workbook can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f3gjkXLXZBe-12qxxTpmVFyNs6rWKDDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple mistake. You forgot the sheet reference.

Change this

```dart
ISNUMBER(B$40:B$103)
```

to this

```dart
ISNUMBER('Initial data collection sheet'!B$40:B$103)
```

Comment: @elephants_neve_forget You're welcome, Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the grey tick at the top-left of this answer so the question is marked as resolved.